# vectorization Matlab - how to vectorize Gauss function ( code ) without loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization, gaussian, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

i wrote a function to calculate the integral using gaussian quadrature rule. I need to vectorize the last 2 lines, without using a loop. Any ideas?

```
function Q = gauss5(f,a,b,n)
    % Divide the interval into n parts
    y = linspace(a,b,n);
    % Create function to use arrayfun
    % Sum up the result from the arrayfun with function Fun on particular
    % intervals, the first argument is array y without the last value, and
    % the second argument is the array y without the first value
    a  = (y(1:end-1));
    b = (y(2:end));
    % coefficients - some random numbers
    c = [1 2 3 4 5];
    % nodes - random numbers too
    x = [1 1 1 1 1];
    % calculate b-a
    w = b-a;
    % sum up the result
    Q = 0;
    for i=1:n-1
    Q = Q + sum((w(i)*c.*feval(f,((w(i)*x)+a(i)))));
    end
end
```

Comment: Is f can be different functions? And is `n` always less than length of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

If your `f` can get an array as input, you can replace this:

```
% sum up the result
Q = 0;
for i=1:n-1
    Q = Q + sum((w(i)*c.*feval(f,((w(i)*x)+a(i)))));
end
```

by this:

```
wxa = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@times,w,x(:)),a);
Qs = bsxfun(@times,w,c(:)).*feval(f,wxa);
Q = sum(Qs(:))
```

Or, if you have Matlab 2016b or later, just:

```
Qs = w.*c(:).*feval(f,w.*x(:)+a);
Q1 = sum(Qs(:));
```